# feedback on dual boot parition sceheme (ubuntu + windows7)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I recently did some research in disk partitioning and came up with the below scheme for my 500GB HD (dual boot Ubuntu + Windows 7, with some scope for experimenting with other OSes). Would be great to get some feedback on the same. I came across these concepts UEFI, MBR, GPT etc but i'm still not sure how they impact me and was planing to just use defaults as i go.

```
75GB  NTFS Primary [windows7]
20GB  NTFS Primary [experimenting with OSes that only install on primary partitions]
Extended Parition
  8GB  linux-swap [1xRAM]
  75G  Ext4 [For Ubuntu]
  50GB EXT4 [Another spare partition for another linux variant]
  125 GB NTFS data1 [NTFS because supported by most linux and windows]
  125 GB NTFS data2 [NTFS because supported by most linux and windows]
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you boot in legacy mode, it looks good.

If you boot EFI mode, it is preferable to format the drive gpt. Then all partitions can be primary. The first partition needs to be a 500 MB partition formatted to FAT32 and flagged as ESP (EFI System Partition). This partition is where the boot loaders go for the EFI system to boot from.
Behind this partition you can add the rest as primary partitions sized as you have described.

Comment: How do we choose to boot UEFI mode? Is there some option in the windows/ubuntu installation process where we need to specify this?

Comment: in the computer system settings. if it is a computer that supports UEFI